# create-react-app can't find react in tests when aliased with preact

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, create-react-app, preact

I have created a project with "create-react-app". I have added preact to the project by ejecting it and using alias in webpack config.

```
alias: {
      'react': 'preact-compat-enzyme',
      'react-dom': 'preact-compat-enzyme',
      'react-dom/server': 'preact-render-to-string',
      'react-addons-test-utils': 'preact-test-utils',
      'react-addons-transition-group': 'preact-transition-group'
    }
```

This works in the code and I am able to render the app. But, in tests I am getting the following error

```
Cannot find module 'react' from 'App.test.js'
```

Why can't it find the module? Is there something that we have to add to config other than alias?

Answer (score 1):

This took some digging but, I got it working by adding following in in moduleNameMapper package.json.

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react$": "preact-compat-enzyme",
      "^react-dom$": "preact-compat-enzyme",
      "^react-dom/server$": "preact-render-to-string",
      "^react-addons-test-utils$": "preact-test-utils",
      "^react-addons-transition-group$": "preact-transition-group",
},
```